# SMTP and XMPP deployment/workflow

Tags: python, deployment, smtp, xmpp

I'm developing a website that incorporates an XMPP bot and a custom SMTP server (mainly these services process commands and reply).  I'd like to set up a system where I can develop locally, push changes to a staging server, and finally to a production system.  (Essentially I'm developing on the live server currently.)

I'm using python, and I'm reading a bit about fabric, but I'm running into a mental block.

I am using sqlalchemy-migrate to manage database versions and have the basic DNS stuff set up for the host.  Additionally, I have a library that I'm currently working on that these two services both use (in my global site-packages directory).  I deploy this egg after I change anything.  This would ideally also be deployable, but only available to the correct version.  Would I need two versions, stage-lib and live-lib?  Is this possible with python eggs?

Would I need another host to act as a staging server for these services?  Or is there a way to tell DNS that something@staging.myhost.com goes to a different port than 25?

I have a fabfile right now that has a bunch of methods like stage_smtp, stage_xmpp, live_smtp, live_xmpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: DNS has no way to tell you to connect to a non-standard SMTP port, even with SRV records.  (XMPP does.)

So, for sending email, you'll have to do something like:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost:2525')
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```